# Lead and Lag in SQL

Tags: sql

My table has the following columns: `product_id`, `customer_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `product`, `product_use`. My goal is to find what product the customer was using at the beginning of the each month as well as end of the each month? Any ideas how to do this in SQL? Thanks.

```
product_id   cust_id    START_DT    END_DT
8398D           8678    12/18/2013  3/10/2014
270B9           8678    2/14/2014   3/16/2014
C0867           8678    3/25/2014   4/1/2014
2F9D2           8678    4/3/2014    5/7/2014
9AE65           8678    4/25/2014   5/6/2014
```

expected results

```
Month    product_begining_of_month     product_end_of_month 
December        8398D                  8398D
January         8398D                  8398D
February        8398D                  8398D and 270B9  
March           8398D and 270B9        C0867
April           2F9D2                  2F9D2 AND 9AE65
```

Comment: Please specify your database platform by tagging it in the question (eg MySQL, Sql Server...)

Comment: What is your expected output from your sample data?

Comment: @paqogomez: as he/she mentions lag() and lead() it's most probably Oracle, Postgres or SQL Server 2012

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Here is may attemptselect x.cust_id,x.start_month,min(x.product_id_beg) as product_id_beg,max(x.product_id_end) as product_id_end  from(  select t.*,  case when t.start_dt=min(t.start_dt)over (partition by t.cust_id,t.start_month) then t.product_id  end product_id_beg,  case when t.start_dt=max(t.start_dt)over (partition by t.cust_id,t.start_month) then t.product_id  end product_id_end  from TEST_INSERT t)x  group by x.cust_id,x.start_month

Comment: @paqogomez this is what I expect  product beginning of month product end of month
December 8398D 8398D
January 8398D 8398D
February 8398D 8398D and 270B9
March 8398D and 270B9 C0867
April 2F9D2 2F9D2 AND 9AE65

Comment: That expected result doesnt make much sense as its formatted in the comment.  Could you format it nicely and put it in your original post please?

Comment: @paqogomez see the formatted expected results above..thanks

Comment: I would still like to know which platform you're on.

Answer (score 0):

you could select the ids, and first and last dates as a result set; then use an outer table query these results to select the productId using the inner table results of the dates and customerid..

```
  SELECT CustID, (SELECT product_id FROM CustomerTable CTBL2 WHERE 
 (CustID=INNTBL.CustID and  (TranscationDate=INNTBL.LastmostDate)) AS
LastmostProduct, (SELECT product_id FROM CustomerTable CTBL3 WHERE 
  (CustID=INNTBL.CustID_ and (TranscationDate=INNTBL.FirstDate)) AS FirstProduct 
      FROM 
  (Select CustId, Max(TranscationDate) AS LastmostDate, 
   Min(TranscationDate) as FirstDate FROM CustomerTable as CTBL
   Group by CustId) AS INNTBL
```

Comment: Thanks guys for prompt response. I'm using Oracle 8i (PL/SQL). Here is what I tried to do...but caused errors..

Comment: select x.cust_id,x.start_month,min(x.product_id_beg) as product_id_beg,max(x.product_id_end) as product_id_end         
from(         
select t.*,         
case when t.start_dt=min(t.start_dt)over (partition by t.cust_id,t.start_month) then t.product_id         
 end product_id_beg,         
    case when t.start_dt=max(t.start_dt)over (partition by t.cust_id,t.start_month) then t.product_id         
      end product_id_end         
 from TEST_INSERT t)x         
         
group by x.cust_id,x.start_month

Comment: this is my expected results... product beginning of month product end of month
December 8398D 8398D
January 8398D 8398D
February 8398D 8398D and 270B9
March 8398D and 270B9 C0867
April 2F9D2 2F9D2 AND 9AE65